# Trying to figure out deploy error with locomotivecms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, carrierwave, locomotivecms

I am trying to deploy my site to my locomotivecms site, everything is working but this its something to do with my carrier wave file could someone point out what is wrong with it.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.cache_dir = File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'uploads')

  case Rails.env.to_sym

  when :development
    config.storage = :file
    config.root = File.join(Rails.root, 'public')

  when :production
    # the following configuration works for Amazon S3
    config.storage          = :fog
    config.fog_credentials  = {
      :provider =>                 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id =>       'AKIAI5GMSOQ',
      :aws_secret_access_key =>    '1Q7g8TXCmFmmkS',

    }
    config.fog_directory  = 'portfolioanders'

  else
    # settings for the local filesystem
    config.storage = :file
    config.root = File.join(Rails.root, 'public')
  end

end
```

Here is my wagon.log

```
* Reloaded "site", "content_types", "pages", "snippets", "content_entries", "translations" at 2013-10-07 23:59:47 -0700
The API key is invalid. (401)
unable to get an API token: The API key is invalid. (401)
* Reloaded "site", "content_types", "pages", "snippets", "content_entries", "translations" at 2013-10-08 00:02:07 -0700
* Reloaded "site", "content_types", "pages", "snippets", "content_entries", "translations" at 2013-10-08 15:43:41 -0700
[0;31;49m      error => Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
[0m
[0;31;49m      error => Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
[0m
[0;31;49m      error => Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
[0m
[0;31;49m      error => Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
[0m
* Reloaded "site", "content_types", "pages", "snippets", "content_entries", "translations" at 2013-10-08 19:53:34 -0700
[0;31;49m      error => Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
[0m
[0;31;49m      error => Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
[0m
[0;31;49m      error => Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
[0m
[0;31;49m      error => Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
[0m
```

Comment: I hope you have not posted your actual AWS credentials. The error reads "The API key is invalid". Are your credentials correct? Do these credentials have access to the s3 bucket?

Comment: oops just fixed that, how do i check if they have access to the s3 bucket?

Comment: Use any method you like. `rails console` is not a bad idea. There are s3 clients available such as `S3Fox`, `s3browser`, `s3cmd`. Any one of these should be able to tell you if the keys are valid. Best is to dig into the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go to the Iam section in the console and create a group and user which had connection to s3 and created a different access key and secret pass

Comment: Could you explain this answer in more detail? I am having the same error and I am not pushing to AWS at all.

Comment: NVM, I see what you are talking about now the AWS settings are thrown into the Carrierwave init by default. I commented them out. TY